# Creating Trigger function in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to create a trigger function in the PostgreSQL database with pgAdmin 4. The function should perform pg_notify and return newly inserted data in JSON. But I'm getting the error and can't figure out where is a mistake.

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ba_weather.weather_notify_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$ CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weather_notify_func()
 RETURNS TRIGGER
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $$
 BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('weather_insert', row_to_json(NEW));
    RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $$;$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION ba_weather.weather_notify_func()
   OWNER TO me;
```

Error:

```
enter code here
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 5: AS $BODY$ CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weather_notify_func()
^
```

The solution is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ba_weather.weather_notify_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$ 
 BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('weather_insert', row_to_json(NEW));
    RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION ba_weather.weather_notify_func()
   OWNER TO me;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nested the function definition again into the create function statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ba_weather.weather_notify_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$ 
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('weather_insert', row_to_json(NEW));
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION ba_weather.weather_notify_func()
   OWNER TO me;
```